# Splitting field over K of an infinite set of polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $F$ is a finite splitting field over $K$ of $X=\lbrace f_i(x)\rbrace_{i\in I}$, some infinite set. Is there necessarily a finite set $Y\subseteq X$ such that $F$ is a finite splitting field of $Y$?

I'm curious if there is a way to generalize: $F$  is a splitting field over $K$ of a finite set $\lbrace f_1,…,f_n\rbrace$ of polynomials in $K[x]$ if and only if $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of the single polynomial $f=f_1f_2⋯f_n$.

The example I have in mind is $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $\mathbb{C}$ is the splitting field for $X=\lbrace ax^2+bx+c\mid a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}, b^2-4ac<0 \rbrace$ and but also for just $x^2+1$.

Comment: No, in general it is not possible to find a finite subset. If you could, as you note, the finite subset could then be replaced by a single polynomial, and so the extension would necessarily be a finite extension. However, you can find infinite extensions, e.g., of $\mathbb{Q}$: the extension given by the splitting field of the set of polynomials $f_n(x) = x^n-1$ for all $n\geq 1$ is not given as the splitting field of *any* finite set of polynomials, let alone a subset of $\{f_n\}$.

Comment: That was another example I was thinking about. Although $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},...)$ is an infinite extension. If we assumed our restriction was finite then could we, for some reason, take some finite subset?

Comment: If the extensions is finitely generated and algebraic, then it is finite, and then you can take a single polynomial.

Comment: Yes, this is actually what I'm trying to prove. This issue has arised because the question is worded in such a way that our only assumption is that the extension is finite and normal. Then I am to prove that it is the splitting field of a single polynomial. 

So I'm curious if the set of polynomials can always be finite.

Comment: No, “a set of polynomials can always be finite” is not correct, as already noted. But a finite extension is **necessarily** finitely generated, and you only need one polynomial for each generator, and then you can take the product of all of these polynomials.

Comment: Ah, I see. How could one guarantee that $K$ will split these polynomials? I'm tempted to use the fact that: $K$ is a splitting field if and only if every irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ that has a root in $K$ splits completely in $K[x]$. Although I can't since I've used what I'm trying to prove here to prove that statement.

Comment: If you are trying to prove that a splitting field is normal, then I think you’ll have a hard time proving it. But then, I wouldn’t understand why you believe you the statement in question (which as you gave it is false in any case, and even in the correct situation given is not required to establish that splitting fields are normal).

Answer (score 0):

It is a classic result in Galois theory that a finite extension $F/K$ is the splitting field of a single polynomial (i.e. generated by all the roots of a single polynomial) if and only if $F/K$ is *normal*, i.e. every irreducible polynomial in $K$ with a root in $F$ splits completely. See [this post, for instance.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380437/k-is-a-splitting-field-iff-any-irreducible-polynomial-with-a-root-in-k-sp?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, this is the question I was being asked. But was worded in such a way that we don't necessarily have a finite set of polynomials. When our set was finite I had already produced a proof. If the extension is finite and the set of polynomials is infinite then as of right now my proof doesn't apply.