# Does a polynomial with multiple roots has a Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

For example,suppose $f(x)$ is a irreducible polynomial on $\mathbb Q$ which can be written as $f(x)=(x-x_1)^{r_1}(x-x_2)^{r_2}\cdots(x-x_n)^{r_n}$ where $r_i>1$,$r_i$ is not all equal,$x_i\notin \mathbb Q$ and $E=\mathbb Q(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is the splitting field of $\mathbb Q$.Now consider the Galois group $Gal(E/\mathbb Q)$,if $\sigma$ is any element of it,then $f(x)$ is unchanged under the action of $\sigma$,but the action on $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a permutation and since $r_i$ is not all equal $(x-x_1)^{r_1}(x-x_2)^{r_2}\cdots(x-x_n)^{r_n}$ must be changed.So is this a contradiction?unless $Gal(E/\mathbb Q)$ is identity

Edit:Maybe different book has different definition,the $Gal(E/\mathbb Q)$ what I write here means $\mathrm{Aut}(E/\Bbb{Q})$,that is,I'm not assuming that $E/\Bbb{Q}$ must be a Galois extension

Comment: Are you familiar with separability?  That every algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is separable?  That this property places very small limits on the $r_i$?

Comment: @EricTowers Could you be more specific,I don't understand what you mean

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension

Comment: @EricTowers I know separable extension,but how does it have to do with my question

Comment: You say $E$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.  This forces $E$ separable.  This forces $f$ separable.  So no $r_i \geq 2$.

Comment: @EricTowers why I see the wiki say it is not necessarily separable about the definition of splitting field

Comment: You should carefully read the section "Separable and inseparable polynomials" keeping in mind both "$\Bbb{Q}$ has characteristic zero (hence not prime characteristic" and "there are fields of prime characteristic".

Comment: @EricTowers I see,thank you.But now if I add a assumption that the field is prime characteristic,it still seems to get  the contradition following the same procedure

Comment: Not quite.  When you write $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\Bbb{Q})$, you requires that $E$ is a Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, so is normal and separable.   When you want to study the group of automorphisms of an extension that is not Galois, you would write $\mathrm{Aut}(E/\Bbb{Q})$ (because Galois groups are (only) defined for Galois extensions...).  You then get a group of automorphisms, but it is not a Galois group.

Comment: @EricTowers Well,what I learnt from my book is a bit different.The definition of Galois group in the book is just the set of automorphism,and $|\mathrm{Gal}(E/\Bbb{Q})|\leq |E/\mathbb Q|$(of course here assume finite extension) where the equality is taken exactly when it's a Galois extension.So my initial meaning should be in the background of $\mathrm{Aut}(E/\Bbb{Q})$

Comment: @EricTowers Not all authors agree. For example Jacobson denotes $Gal L/K$ what you may call $Aut(L/K)$. This is a convention like many others.

Comment: But, 1) If $E$ is the splitting field, this implies that $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois. 2) The fact that $f(x)$ is irreducible together with the rationals having characteristic zero  implies that $r_i=1$ for all $i$. The reason is that in characteristic zero the derivative $f'(x)$ would have $x_1$ as a zero of degree $r_1-1$. If $r_1>1$ this implies that $\gcd(f(x),f'(x))$ is a proper factor of $f(x)$ with rational coefficients. Hence $f(x)$ cannot be irreducible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen 1)Why if $E$ is the splitting field then $E/\Bbb{Q}$ must be Galois extension?2)  if I add a assumption that the field is prime characteristic,then following the same procedure it still seems to get the contradition

Comment: In characteristic $p$ it is possible that $f'(x)$ is the zero polynomial, when the gcd does not give a proper factor. A splitting field of a polynomial is a normal extension. Normal + separable = Galois. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4287390/11619) for a recent discussion. Older and more complete ones undoubtedly exist, but I don't have time to look for one. The details depend on how a Galois extension is defined for you.

Comment: If a polynomial over any field of char 0 has multiple root (in the algebraic closure of the field) then it is not irreducible because it has a common non-trivial divisor with its derivative.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote proves that for any field $K$ and any irreducible $f \in K[x]$ that splits in a larger extension $L$, writing $f = \prod_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)^{r_i}$, we must actually have $r_1 = \cdots = r_n$.

Indeed, what you found is a contradiction, but the problematic assumption is that there exists such an irreducible $f$ with different $r_i$'s.

This makes sense in the bigger picture: if $K$ has characteristic $0$ then automatically $f$ is separable, so $r_i = 1$ for all $i$;

and if $K$ has characteristic $p > 0$, then there exists a **separable** irreducible polynomial $g(x)$ and a natural number $d \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = g(x^{p^d})$. Then, writing $g(x) = (x-y_1) \cdots (x-y_n)$, and letting $x_i$ be the $(p^d)$<sup>th</sup> root of $y_i$ (which is unique), we have $f(x) = (x-x_1)^{p^d} \cdots (x-x_n)^{p^d}$, so indeed $r_1 = \cdots r_n = p^d$.